# Sql prepared statement execute() error

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to use prepared statement for my PHP `SELECT` query but i get this error

> SQLite3Stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\post.php on line 75

What could be wrong here? I ma referencing the answer i got [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167343/prepared-statements-in-php)

But this doesn't work.Below is my code.

```
$postid = (int) $_GET['post_id'];

$userpostquery = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($userpostquery);
$stmt->execute([$postid]);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $cname = $row['cname'];

    echo $cname;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$stmt->execute([$postid]);` remove `[$postid]`. start with that.

Comment: Seems like you are using http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php, not http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php To bind see http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if i do that how would i now get what i am looking for in the `$userpostquery` that is `bindValue ? with #postid`.

Comment: see the links that @chris85 posted.

Comment: Thanks @chris85. Does this mean i don't need `PDO` when fetching with the `while` loop. Because the current code does'nt fetch.?

Comment: You can't use sqlite **and** PDO, they are different drivers. You need to use all the functions of whichever **one** you are using.

Comment: Thanks very much @chris85

Comment: I feel this falls as a duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: So replace `$stmt->execute([$postid]);` with `$stmt->execute();` and prior to that `$stmt->bindValue(1, $postid, SQLITE3_INTEGER);`

Comment: Thanks @chris85. All works fine now. But is this enough to prevent sql injection?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't put the user data directly in query so it can't be manipulated

Comment: Alright Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though `SQLite` syntax is similar to `PDO`, you can't pass parameters in `execute` (see the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php, no arguments to this function are available). So you need to use `bindParam`/`bindValue`.

Second, [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php) method returns `SQLiteResult`, you should iterate over it, now over `$stmt`.

Third, [SQLiteResult](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php) has **no** `fetch` method, only [`fetchArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php).
And fourth - as you don't use `PDO`, `PDO::` constants are useless.

```
$postid = (int) $_GET['post_id'];

$userpostquery = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($userpostquery);
// treat $postid as INTEGER
$stmt->bindParam(1, $postid, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
// get SQLiteResult
$result = $stmt->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) 
{
    $cname = $row['cname'];

    echo $cname;
}
```